# seaborn color_palette as matplotlib colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Seaborn offers a function called color_palette, which allows you to easily create new color_palettes for plots.

```
colors = ["#67E568","#257F27","#08420D","#FFF000","#FFB62B","#E56124","#E53E30","#7F2353","#F911FF","#9F8CA6"]

color_palette = sns.color_palette(colors)
```

I want to transform color_palette to a cmap, which I can use in matplotlib, but I don't see how I can do this.

Sadly just functions like "cubehelix_palette","light_palette",… have an "as_cmap" paramater. "color_palette" doesn't, unfortunately.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to convert a list of colors from seaborn palette to color map of matplolib (thx to @RafaelLopes for proposed changes):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# construct cmap
flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"]
my_cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette(flatui).as_hex())

N = 500
data1 = np.random.randn(N)
data2 = np.random.randn(N)
colors = np.linspace(0,1,N)
plt.scatter(data1, data2, c=colors, cmap=my_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong, but this doesn't look like a transformation of a seaborn color_palette to a matplotlib cmap, this looks like an alternative solution on how to make a colormap with matplotlib. 
If I remove
     sns.set_palette(flatui)
from your code nothing changes. Nevertheless thanks for showing this matplotlib functionality.

Comment: This is the correct answer in terms of functionality, but please don't use discrete sets of colors to map continuously varying data, it is very misleading.

Comment: Based on this answer @Corrumpo you code use `cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette().as_hex())`

Comment: @RafaelLopes thanks for your comment! This is very helpful and allows practically using every seaborn palette directly in matplotlib! :)

Comment: Note that this answer creates a matplotlib colormap from a list of colors. There is no need to use seaborn here at all, the above code could be done completely without the use of seaborn. It seems that the original version of this answer actually did exactly that, using `my_cmap = ListedColormap(flatui)`.

Answer (score 43):

Most seaborn methods to generate color palettes have an optional argument `as_cmap` which by default is `False`. You can use to directly get a Matplotlib colormap:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# construct cmap
my_cmap = sns.light_palette("Navy", as_cmap=True)

N = 500
data1 = np.random.randn(N)
data2 = np.random.randn(N)
colors = np.linspace(0,1,N)
plt.scatter(data1, data2, c=colors, cmap=my_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 31):

The first answer is somehow correct but way too long with a lot of unnecessary information. The correct and short answer is:

To convert any `sns.color_palette()` to a matplotlib compatible cmap you need two lines of code

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette())
```

Comment: And for the opposite? Is there a similar code to convert a matplotlib colormap like `[0.0, 'rgb(30, 136, 229)'], [0.01, 'rgb(30, 135, 228)'], ...` into a seaborn compatible color palette?

Answer (score 12):

Just an additional tip - if one wants a continuous colorbar/colormap, adding 256 as the number of colors required from Seaborn colorscheme helps a lot.

```
cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("Spectral",256))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas plots (which are matplotlib plots) need `ListedColormap` to define a list of colors. They can also use seaborn colour palettes directly if they have been created with the `as_cmap=True` argument.

Create a sample dataset

```
import pandas
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
df = pandas.DataFrame({'x':range(0,30), 'y':range(10,40)})
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)
df["z"] = 39
df["a"] = 10
```

Use a simple list of colours to plot 3 data frame columns (this doesn't require seaborn)

```
df.plot(colormap=ListedColormap(["red","green","orange"]), figsize=(3,3))
plt.show()
```

[image: plot illustrating a change in palette]

Use a seaborn palette defined with the `as_cmap=True` argument:

```
palette = seaborn.color_palette("rocket_r", as_cmap=True)
df.plot(colormap=palette, figsize=(3,3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks to Serenity, Generic Wevers and Ramon Crehuet for their answers.