# using a custom colour scheme in pandas/matplotlib/seaborn python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

I want to use a custom colour scheme using for various plots but can't get it to work (using seaborn and/or matplob & pandas for these plots)

```
flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"]
ax = sns.violinplot(x="Contents", y="Flavour", data=rd, color="lol", inner="box")
```

I get error code:

```
ValueError: to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "flatui"
could not convert string to float: 'flatui'
```

even

```
ax = sns.violinplot(x="Contents", y="Flavour", data=rd, color=["9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"], inner="box")
```

doesnt work

help please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use seaborns color\_palette as a colormap in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902459/how-do-i-use-seaborns-color-palette-as-a-colormap-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try this.

```
flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"]
sns.set_palette(flatui)
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette())

ax = sns.violinplot(x="Contents", y="Flavour", data=rd, color="lol", inner="box")
```

With some other data here are the results.

[image]

Comment: How would I go about doing this in just a matplotlib plot such as:

grouped = rd.groupby(["Packet number", "Flavour"])["Contents"].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
grouped.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, colormap=["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"])

as this way does not work with your suggestion

Comment: grouped.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, color=["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"])  Does that work?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set colours via palettes in Seaborn or you can pass Violinplot the colours directly via the 'palette' parameter rather than 'color'. It's all in the [Seaborn docs.](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html#seaborn.violinplot)

Comment: yep, tried with palette also, just used color as one way to fix the problem, neither worked initially