# How to use the same color palette across matplotlib / seaborn subplots?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am making a set of subplots with matplotlib and seaborn and I would like the color palette to be the same between the top and the bottom subplots.

What is odd is that with some types of plots (e.g. lineplot at the top and distplot at the bottom) the palette is automatically the same. With others (e.g. regplot at the top and distplot at the bottom) it is not.

This is an example of what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import itertools

sns.set(style='darkgrid')

x = np.arange(1,1001)
x=np.random.lognormal(0,1,1001)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(2,1)

sns.lineplot(x, x*2, label ='2x', ax=ax1[0])
sns.lineplot(x, x*3, label ='3x', ax=ax1[0])

sns.distplot( 2*x, bins = 100, ax = ax1[1], label='2x'  )
sns.distplot( 3*x, bins = 100, ax = ax1[1], label='3x'  )

for a in ax1:
    a.legend()


fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(2,1)
sns.regplot(x, x*2, label ='2x', ax=ax2[0])
sns.regplot(x, x*3, label ='3x', ax=ax2[0])

sns.distplot( 2*x, bins = 100, ax = ax2[1], label='2x'  )
sns.distplot( 3*x, bins = 100, ax = ax2[1], label='3x'  )

for a in ax2:
    a.legend()
```

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823078/how-to-sync-colors-across-subplots-of-different-types-seaborne-matplotlib) , the code below does work.

However, I was wondering:

1. Why is the palette the same with some plots but not with others? What's the technical reason?
2. Is there a more elegant way to reset the palette without having to specify `color = next(palette)` every single time?

Code:

```
palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette())

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(2,1)
sns.regplot(x, x*2, label ='2x', ax=ax3[0], color = next(palette) )
sns.regplot(x, x*3, label ='3x', ax=ax3[0], color = next(palette))

palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette())

sns.distplot( 2*x, bins = 100, ax = ax3[1], label='2x', color = next(palette)  )
sns.distplot( 3*x, bins = 100, ax = ax3[1], label='3x' , color = next(palette) )

for a in ax3:
    a.legend()
```

Comment: This is unexpected indeed. Note that the palette is always the same. It's called property cycle. The interesting bit is that lineplot+distplot show the first two colors of that cycle in each axes, as one would expect. But regplot+distplot show the first two colors in the first axes and color 3 and 4 in the other axes. That is quite surprising.

Comment: Worthy of a bug report?