# Error when specifying cmap in plt.matshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I get an error every time when I try to define the cmap while calling sns.color_palette(). I think it has something to do with the definition of the color palette but I am not sure:

```
colors = ["#1d4877", "#1b8a5a", "#fbb021", "#f68838", "#ee3e32"]
sns.set_palette(colors)
```

And when I try to set it:

```
plt.matshow(num1.corr(), cmap=sns.color_palette())
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: [(0.11372549019607843, 0.2823529411764706, 0.4666666666666667), (0.10588235294117647, 0.5411764705882353, 0.35294117647058826), (0.984313725490196, 0.6901960784313725, 0.12941176470588237), (0.9647058823529412, 0.5333333333333333, 0.2196078431372549), (0.9333333333333333, 0.24313725490196078, 0.19607843137254902)] is not a valid value for cmap; supported values are 'Accent', 'Accent_r', 'Blues', 'Blues_r', 'BrBG', 'BrBG_r', 'BuGn', 'BuGn_r', 'BuPu', 'BuPu_r', 'CMRmap', 'CMRmap_r', 'Dark2', 'Dark2_r', 'GnBu', 'GnBu_r', 'Greens', 'Greens_r', 'Greys', 'Greys_r', 'OrRd', 'OrRd_r', 'Oranges', 'Oranges_r', 'PRGn', 'PRGn_r', 'Paired', 'Paired_r', 'Pastel1', 'Pastel1_r', 'Pastel2', 'Pastel2_r', 'PiYG', 'PiYG_r', 'PuBu', 'PuBuGn', 'PuBuGn_r', 'PuBu_r', 'PuOr', 'PuOr_r', 'PuRd', 'PuRd_r', 'Purples', 'Purples_r', 'RdBu', 'RdBu_r', 'RdGy', 'RdGy_r', 'RdPu', 'RdPu_r', 'RdYlBu', 'RdYlBu_r', 'RdYlGn', 'RdYlGn_r', 'Reds', 'Reds_r', 'Set1', 'Set1_r', 'Set2', 'Set2_r', 'Set3', 'Set3_r', 'Spectral', 'Spectral_r', 'Wistia', 'Wistia_r', 'YlGn', 'YlGnBu', 'YlGnBu_r', 'YlGn_r', 'YlOrBr', 'YlOrBr_r', 'YlOrRd', 'YlOrRd_r', 'afmhot', 'afmhot_r', 'autumn', 'autumn_r', 'binary', 'binary_r', 'bone', 'bone_r', 'brg', 'brg_r', 'bwr', 'bwr_r', 'cividis', 'cividis_r', 'cool', 'cool_r', 'coolwarm', 'coolwarm_r', 'copper', 'copper_r', 'crest', 'crest_r', 'cubehelix', 'cubehelix_r', 'flag', 'flag_r', 'flare', 'flare_r', 'gist_earth', 'gist_earth_r', 'gist_gray', 'gist_gray_r', 'gist_heat', 'gist_heat_r', 'gist_ncar', 'gist_ncar_r', 'gist_rainbow', 'gist_rainbow_r', 'gist_stern', 'gist_stern_r', 'gist_yarg', 'gist_yarg_r', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'gnuplot2_r', 'gnuplot_r', 'gray', 'gray_r', 'hot', 'hot_r', 'hsv', 'hsv_r', 'icefire', 'icefire_r', 'inferno', 'inferno_r', 'jet', 'jet_r', 'magma', 'magma_r', 'mako', 'mako_r', 'nipy_spectral', 'nipy_spectral_r', 'ocean', 'ocean_r', 'pink', 'pink_r', 'plasma', 'plasma_r', 'prism', 'prism_r', 'rainbow', 'rainbow_r', 'rocket', 'rocket_r', 'seismic', 'seismic_r', 'spring', 'spring_r', 'summer', 'summer_r', 'tab10', 'tab10_r', 'tab20', 'tab20_r', 'tab20b', 'tab20b_r', 'tab20c', 'tab20c_r', 'terrain', 'terrain_r', 'turbo', 'turbo_r', 'twilight', 'twilight_r', 'twilight_shifted', 'twilight_shifted_r', 'viridis', 'viridis_r', 'vlag', 'vlag_r', 'winter', 'winter_r'

I also tried calling the sns.color_palette() function like this:

```
plt.matshow(num1.corr(), cmap=sns.color_palette(as_cmap=True))
plt.show()
```

and it still produced the same error.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902765/6394617)

Comment: Looks like this bug is responsible: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3448. `sns.color_palette()` doesn't properly handle `as_cmap=True` when you don't give it an explicit palette (i.e. you just want the current palette).

Comment: @slothrop this now makes much more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use matplotib's [`ListedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html)

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

colors = ["#1d4877", "#1b8a5a", "#fbb021", "#f68838", "#ee3e32"]
plt.matshow(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4), cmap=ListedColormap(colors))
```

*Note however, that this cmap is not suitable if you have continuous data.*

Output:

[image]

Comment: Well it sure is a bummer that sns.ColorPalette is not compatible with plt.ColorPalette or ListedColors.